# Bad SQL Grammar Exception Springboot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc

I am using JDBC in Springboot. I get Bad SQL Grammar Exception with the following query even though the query works fine directly on the MySQL workbench. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I am using Java 17. Springboot 3.0.6.

```
public int fetchUserByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) {
    try
    {
        String sql = "SELECT userId FROM authentication.user WHERE email= 'abc@gmail.com' AND password= '12345';";
        //String sql = "SELECT userId FROM authentication.user WHERE email='" + email + "' AND password='" + password +"';";
        return getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);
    } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException e)
    {
        return 0;
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of your query string.

Comment: Also, the commented out query is not something you should use as it makes you vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use proper parameters.

Comment: @seenukarthi same issue without the ; as well

Comment: replace `System.out.println(e);` with `e.printStackTrace()` and add the stacktrace to you question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to remove the `;` from the end.

Comment: Removing the ; didn't fix it

Comment: Please include the stack trace into the question please.